# First photo in array is missing when trying to display images

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with images. I have written a function that loops through this array and displays every image. But for some reason the first image in the array is not displayed on the page.

```
function replacePhotoFlags($auto, $output) {
    $fotos = explode("," , $auto['fotos']);
    $count = 0;
    print_r($fotos);
    foreach($fotos as $key=>$foto){
        $img_url = FOTO_URL . '/' . get_option("ac") . '/foto/' . $foto;
        if(@file_get_contents($img_url, 0, null, 0, 1)) {
            $fotoURL = '<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="' . $img_url . '"><img src="' . $img_url . '" /></a>';
            $output = str_replace("<<-- foto_medium_lightbox" . $key . " -->>", $fotoURL, $output);
            $count++;
        } else {
            $output = str_replace("<<-- foto_medium_lightbox" . $key . " -->>", "", $output);
        }

    }

    for($i = $count; $i <= 24; $i++) {
        $output = str_replace("<<-- foto_medium_lightbox" . $i - 1 . " -->>", "", $output);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

The print_r($fotos) shows the first photo, but in the foreach it is missing.
Any ideas why it's not showing?

print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => 133494746501.JPG [1] => 133494746502.JPG [2] => 133494746503.JPG [3] => 1334947465039.JPG [4] => 133494746504.JPG [5] => 133494746505.JPG [6] => 133494746506.JPG [7] => 133494746507.JPG [8] => 133494746508.JPG [9] => 133494746509.JPG [10] => 133494746510.JPG [11] => 133494746511.JPG [12] => 133494746512.JPG [13] => 1334947465320.JPG [14] => 1334947465368.JPG [15] => 1334947465458.JPG [16] => 1334947465622.JPG [17] => 1334947465867.JPG [18] => 1334947465872.JPG [19] => 1334947465985.JPG )
```

Comment: you're over-riding $output every time with just an = rather than concatenating it with a .=

Comment: No thats not it. because it must be overridden, while it's a string_replace

Comment: If you share your print_r($fotos) or var_dump($fotos) , than I'm gonna tell you. I think the problem is in your foreach statement. If you have a normal array than no need to use $key=$foto.

Comment: `@file_get_contents` evaluates to false ?

Comment: It is false when theres no image. But that's oke because then it will not try to show an image

Comment: What happens when you place a `echo $key;` before your `if(@file_get` clause, does it start off with a 0 or does it start with 1?

Comment: It echo's the first image as well

Comment: My bad. that should be NOT displayed

Comment: If I echo the key in the if(@file_get.... it will start at 1. but before the if it starts with 0. So i thought the key would be used in the else. but it isn't

Comment: They key is used in the else, it's not used in the if clause.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?? maybe its going wrong somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the flag which your key tries to replace doesnt exist because your key starts at 0 and your flag at 1.

```
<<-- foto_medium_lightbox0 -->>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for($i = $count; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $output = str_replace("<<-- foto_medium_lightbox" . $i - 1 . " -->>", "", $output);
}
```

With

```
$count=0;
for($i = $count; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $output = str_replace("<<-- foto_medium_lightbox" . $i - 1 . " -->>", "", $output);
}
```

Comment: because in the if statement you do count++ so the value becomes 1 and thats why you probarly wont get the first image.

Comment: Nicely spotted. - @WouterdenOuden He's correct, you are doing a `$count++;` at the last line of your if clause, and that means that in your for loop the `$i` will start at 1 or higher.

Comment: Thats right but for some reason it works well so. because that for removes every flag thats not filled at all after the foreach. Tried it, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Wait. What I do is allright because the $count shouldn't be 0 at all. Both works but it loops from 0 to 24. but it should go from the amount of photo's to 24.